# Extracting sds from MODIS LAI/FPAR hdf format using gdalUtils library

Tags: r, raster, rgdal

I am trying to extract all layers of the MODIS LAI/FPAR imageries using gdalUTILs library, I am getting this error, could anyone help me out of this
I am trying to use

## Get a list of SDS names

```
sds <- get_subdatasets('MOD15A2H.A2016289.h28v08.006.2016302012314.hdf')
```

## Isolate the name of the first SDS

```
name <- sds[1]`enter code here`
filename <- 'name/of/output/file.tif'
gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = filename)
```

## Load the Geotiff created into R

```
r <- raster(filename)
```

and the error is

```
> sds <- get_subdatasets('MOD15A2H.A2016289.h28v08.006.2016302012314.hdf')
```

Error in split1[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\bin\gdalinfo.exe" "MOD15A2H.A2016289.h28v08.006.2016302012314.hdf"' had a status 1

Comment: i think gdaltranslate wants a filename as input,  while you are trying to pass "data"  to it. You may also be interested in this package,  which should allow to do what you need automatically : https://github.com/lbusett/MODIStsp

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. I am trying to install the package you suggested but this error is coming > install_github("Ibusett/MODIStsp") Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : Couldn't connect to server its may be because of restrictive internet connection, but if this is the case how do I resolve this!??

Comment: Seems possible.  Did you ever try to install a package from github before?

Comment: I don't think so, I am not sure! when we install packages it access cran (R Archive) only right, in that case I haven't. So whats your suggestion?

Comment: Try installing a different package from github (E. G.  install_github("hadley/devtools").  If that fails,  then you can't install from github.  In that case,  you can tryi installing modistsp from source. (I. E.  Download the zip and use R Cmd build).  Or (maybe easier)  clone the modistsp repo in your rstudio as a new git project (you will have to install git on your computer),  and build it with ctrl-shift-b)

Answer (score 1):

Check the hdf file size. If it's 1 or 2kb then its html error file. I had same issue for MOD15A2H product.